# A query fetches 1000 records from the table. The data will be returned as collection. What is the correct approach

Tags: hibernate

A query fetches 1000 records from the table. The data will be returned as collection.

There are two approaches in my point of view:

1. get all the records and paginate them in web layer, or
2. get only some records at a time and when user asks more more, fetch more

What do you think is correct approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your situation. If the user is likely to browse all 1000 records, you can definitely get them in one query.

However, in most cases it's the best is to limit the the number of records while fetching from DB, with `setMaxResults()` of `Criteria` or `Query`. Of course, you should use the ordering key values (e.g. creation timestamp of the records) of current page with your next query when the user clicks on "previous" or "next".